# how do I create a new column in my main data frame filling in the values from a smaller dataset based on two columns they have in common?

Tags: python

I have a dataset that is time series with over 10 000 rows. I need to create a new column and the values of this column are available in a different data set of 200 rows. The similarities between these datasets are the year and country column.

[I want to assign the value when it exists, and when it doesn't return NA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUEXe.png)

so far i have tried :

```
put = []
for column , values in zip(trial['country'],trial['year']):
  for col , val in zip(help_df['countries'],help_df['values%']):
    if col == column:
      put.append(val)
```

but it returns the wrong value because I don't know how to also use the *if statement* for the "years" in the nested loops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`pd.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html):

```
data1 = [ { "country": "argentina", "year": 2019, "value": "0.6%" }, { "country": "chile", "year": 2018, "value": "0.5%" }, { "country": "argentina", "year": 2020, "value": "0.7%" }, { "country": "chile", "year": 2017, "value": "0.5%" }, { "country": "argentina", "year": 2020, "value": "0.7%" }, { "country": "bolivia", "year": 2019, "value": "0.80%" } ]
data2 = [ { "country": "argentina", "year": 2020 }, { "country": "bolivia", "year": 2019 }, { "country": "chile", "year": 2016 }, { "country": "argentina", "year": 2019 }, { "country": "uruguay", "year": 2020 }, { "country": "bolivia", "year": 2018 } ]
values_df = pd.DataFrame(data1)
main_df = pd.DataFrame(data2)
pd.merge(main_df, values_df, how="outer", on=["year", "country"])
```

Output:

```
|    | country   |   year | value   |
|---:|:----------|-------:|:--------|
|  0 | argentina |   2020 | 0.7%    |
|  1 | argentina |   2020 | 0.7%    |
|  2 | bolivia   |   2019 | 0.80%   |
|  3 | chile     |   2016 | nan     |
|  4 | argentina |   2019 | 0.6%    |
|  5 | uruguay   |   2020 | nan     |
|  6 | bolivia   |   2018 | nan     |
|  7 | chile     |   2018 | 0.5%    |
|  8 | chile     |   2017 | 0.5%    |
```